# How to give color to menu items for Navigation drawer in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.android

I have a Navigation Drawer in my Xamarin.Android app, it's menu items have icons that are coloured but when i run, they are greyed.

After searching on Stack, i've found ou that this is coursed by tinting - but all question handle how to disabling tinting in standard android projects. How do I achieve this in Xamarin.Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
navView.ItemIconTintList = null;
```

**Note**: If you are familiar with the Android SDK, to get an equivalent method in Xamarin.Android (usually) is matter of removing the set/get from the name as this is converted to a C# property.